# Переведите пожалуйста представленный ниже код Kotlin на Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-service

Переведите пожалуйста представленный ниже код Kotlin на Java. Очень надо

```
class SimpleService : Service() {
    private val binder = SimpleBinder()
    //...//
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return binder
    }
    inner class SimpleBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService(): SimpleService = this@SimpleService
    }
}

override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
        val binder = service as SimpleService.SimpleBinder
        simpleService = binder.getService()
        bound = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Все переводчики на карантине. Придется брать словарь и переводить самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Android Studio есть такая хорошая штука `Show Kotlin Bytecode`. Делается так:

1. `Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode`
2. Нажимаем кнопку `Decompile`
3. Наслаждаемся результатом.

Используя инструкцию выше, конвертируем ваш код:

```
public final class SimpleService extends Service {
   private final SimpleService.SimpleBinder binder = new SimpleService.SimpleBinder();

   @Nullable
   public IBinder onBind(@Nullable Intent intent) {
      return (IBinder)this.binder;
   }

   public final class SimpleBinder extends Binder {
      @NotNull
      public final SimpleService getService() {
         return SimpleService.this;
      }
   }
}
```

Этот кусок откуда-то с другого класса насколько я понял:

```
public abstract void onServiceConnected (ComponentName name, 
                IBinder service){
        SimpleService.SimpleBinder binder = service as SimpleService.SimpleBinder
        simpleService = binder.getService()
        bound = true
}
```